# The sound of me fits in quite a lot

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> When combined with a number, I form a race. 
>   But combined with my position, it sounds like distaste. 
>   Knock me over and I'm  endless. 
>   But to knock me in early would be careless. 
>   I'm almost the smallest amount in here.  
>   But my value is necessary to your survival out there.

Answer is **one word**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> **EIGHT**

When combined with a number, I form a race.

> A number is a FIGURE.  FIGURE + **EIGHT** gives Figure 8 Racing.
>  (Simultaneously hinted by OP in The Sphinx's Lair and offered by @Hugh Meyers in [a comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52916/the-sound-of-me-fits-in-quite-a-lot#comment162415_52918).)

But combined with my position, it sounds like distaste.

> Eighth letter is H.   H + **EIGHT** ("ATE") sounds like HATE.

Knock me over and I'm endless.

> An **EIGHT** sideways is ∞

But to knock me in early would be careless.

> The **EIGHT**-ball, knocked in early, loses in billiards.

I'm almost the smallest amount in here.

> **EIGHT** BITS = 1 byte, essentially the smallest data object used for information "here" in SE.
>  (From OP's comment on another answer)

But my value is necessary to your survival out there.

> Element **EIGHT** on periodic table is Oxygen, which is absolutely necessary for survival "out there" in the Real World.

Title:

> A *lot* of words end with -ATE, the sound of **EIGHT**.

Comment: While the 800m *does* fit it's not the one I was thinking of. Not a literal number for a hint.

Comment: Perhaps Figure-8 racing? A number is a figure.

Comment: @HughMeyers Nice - I was also fairly inspired from your riddles lately - more so on a thematic sense, as mine is far less clever than yours :)

Comment: Figure 8 Racing makes much more sense than my Eighth Race Pie haha!

Comment: @n_palum Cool! Nice to feel I've made a contribution. I enjoyed your riddle as well.

Comment: Those clues are so good at misdirection, I guessed "eight" almost immediately and then gave up thinking I was nowhere near.

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> 8

2:

> H8

3:

> 8 on its side is the infinity symbol

5:

> It is one of the smaller numbers

If anyone can explain the other clues that would be great, I don't have much time to ponder them currently.

Comment: Title: the word has a few homophones.

Comment: "knocked in early": the 8-ball in the game of pool.

Answer (score 5):

I got ninja'd *twice* while writing this but I'm posting it anyway.

I think you are

> **Eight**

---

When combined with a number, I form a race.

> Not sure, but could be the **800 metres**

But combined with my position, it sounds like distaste.

> H8 => Hate

Knock me over and I'm endless.

> This is the clincher for me: `8` rotated 90 degrees becomes the infinity symbol ∞

But to knock me in early would be careless.

> In 8-ball pool, knocking in the 8-ball before the other seven loses you the game.

I'm almost the smallest amount in here.

> 8 bits = 1 byte

But my value is necessary to your survival out there.

> @Rubio got this one: the 8th element is oxygen, which we need to breathe

Title

> "Eight" is the longest one-syllable number

Comment: One of your lines is actually the intended answer for a different line that both others are missing.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> Eight

When combined with a number, I form a race.

> The 'number' is **Pi**, Eighth Race Pie.

But combined with my position, it sounds like distaste.

> The position in the alphabet is **H**, H8, Hate.

Knock me over and I'm endless.

> Eight (8) 'knocked over' on its side is the infinity symbol.

But to knock me in early would be careless.

> 'Knocking out' the 8-Ball in pool would cause you to lose.

I'm almost the smallest amount in here.

> 8 is one of the lowest numbers.

But my value is necessary to your survival out there.

> Oxygen has an atomic value of 8. Which is necessary for our survival.

Comment: While the race one is interesting, that is not intended, otherwise this adds nothing new from the other existing answers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Eighth Race Pie"? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @n_palum I thought it was a reach!

Comment: @F1Krazy it's a type of chocolate pie.

Comment: @BreakingMyself Ah, I see, that's quite a clever interpretation.